# Update query in Access with variable that can be empty but constraint the prevents update

Tags: sql, vba

ok, so I have an Update query, whithin VBA:

```
dim StatusID as Long

 SQLString = "UPDATE tblRegister SET tblRegister.Status = " & StatusID & " WHERE tblRegister.ID = 'reg01'
```

there is also a table statuses, which contains statusID 1 through 5 with their descriptions.

User can select a status in a combobox. Now, if the user has not selected a status yet (which is ok) the value of StatusID will be 0. The update query will not accept that 0 for there is a relationship between statuses and register.

I cannot set the Long type to -1 or NULL...

Anybody have an idea? (the query is much longer than above, so a simple if Status = 0 then.. will not do.

Comment: What is it that you wish to have happen when StatusID is set to 0? Do you want to default to an actual valid StatusID value, do you want to prevent the Update statement from running, something else perhaps?

Comment: I want to update all the rest of the fields (not shown in example), and put in a null value for the statusID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [IIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)?

```
SQLString = "UPDATE tblRegister" & _
            " SET tblRegister.Status = " & IIF(StatusID=0,"NULL", StatusID) & _
            " WHERE tblRegister.ID = 'reg01'
```